# Python selenium: unable to locate element on a webpage

Tags: python, selenium

```
class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome() #opens chrome to complete the task

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(URL) #uses the URL that was generated at the start of the task
        self.assertIn("adidas", driver.title)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("Add to Bag") #finds the 'add to bag' button (for adidas.com) and clicks it
        elem.send_keys("pycon")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
        selenium.click("Add to Bag")


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Right now i am experimenting with python and trying to make a simple bot for adidas.com that adds a product to the cart. I am using selenium to do so. I try to have selenium click the 'add to bag' button, but when i run i get this error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"Add to Bag"}
```

It cannot find the 'add to bag' button on the website, even though i know its there. what am I doing wrong?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the website url

Comment: Yea, here's the top part of my code:def UrlGen(model, size):
    BaseSize = 550 #size 5, goes up 10 each half size
    ShoeSize = size - 5
    ShoeSize = ShoeSize * 20
    RawSize = ShoeSize + BaseSize
    ShoeSizeCode = int(RawSize)
    URL = 'http://www.adidas.com/us/' + str(model) + '.html?forceSelSize=' + str(model) + '_' + str(ShoeSizeCode)
    return URL
Model = raw_input('Model #')
Size = input('Size: ')

URL = UrlGen(Model, Size)

print(str(URL))

Answer (score 0):

sometimes I am also facing the same problem by getting element by text.It's best way to get an element by XPath.Hope this XPath will solve your problem

```
elem =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Add to Bag']")
```

> Hope getting element by XPath will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to feed the method the `id` attribute of the element not the text. Looking at the page and the docs it seems that

```
selenium.click('add-to-bag')
```

Should get you there.